# Aren't these two statements incompatible in N4140?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Paragraph §8.3.5/8 (emphasis mine):

> If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form “pointer to
>   array of unknown bound of T” or “reference to array of unknown bound
>   of T,” the program is ill-formed. **Functions shall not have a return
>   type of type array** or function, although they may have a return type
>   of type pointer or reference to such things. There shall be no arrays
>   of functions, although there can be arrays of pointers to functions.

Bullet points (5.2.1) and (5.2.1.1) of §8.5.3/5 (emphasis is mine):

> (5.2.1)      — If the initializer expression
>
> (5.2.1.1)     — is an xvalue (but not a bit-field), class prvalue,
>   **array prvalue** or function lvalue and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, or

If I'm wrong with my assumption (in the title), I would appreciate having an example producing a prvalue array.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't the second section you're quoting dealing with references?   Which things do you think are incompatible?

Comment: @mbgda The first statement says that a function doesn't return an array and the second statement mentions the term `array prvalue`, which seem to be incompatible. But Quentin showed another possibility for producing an array prvalue.

Comment: @mbgda `array prvalue is effectively just a reference to an array` This is not correct. An lvalue reference is an lvalue and an rvalue reference is an xvalue. Thus, references are never prvalues.

Comment: I don't think you really read that in context.  I didn't mean it's a reference in language terms (as in `&`) - but it's a reference in the meaning that the memory allocated shouldn't have to be copied over, the compiler is able to generate code that can point to the already-created object after you transfer ownership - kind of like how copy elision works for function returns.  However you raise a good point that the comment is a little ambiguous there - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int main() {
    using Arr = int[];
    auto&& r = Arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return 0;
}
```

Here `r` binds to a prvalue of array type.

Comment: That was clever. Thanks.

Comment: Quick question.  That isn't technically a prvalue, is it?  Doesn't a prvalue specifically refer to an object that does not exist except as an anonymous temporary rvalue, such as a function return value?  Edit - nevermind, misread it.  I see that is *is* an anonymous temporary.  Leaving my description about prvalue though since it may be helpful to others.

Comment: One more thing to expand on this... this doesn't exactly (or at least completely) address OP's question.  You could create `r` in a function and try to return it but you're going to be returning a reference to a temporary value in this case, so it doesn't *quite* address how a valid array prvalue can be returned from a function.  [**This post**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27281568/4421195) addresses how an array can be returned as a subobject prvalue.

Comment: @mbgda The question wasn't how to return an array from a function (it's explicitly disallowed), but if not being able to do so contradicted the existence of array prvalues altogether. Hence, another way of getting an array prvalue.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I didn't realize OP was questioning how an array prvlaue could exist in the first place - thanks for clarifying (+1).

I was under the impression OP was asking how an array prvalue can be returned from a function - which (as you said) it cannot.  If it's part of an non-array aggregate prvalue then it works, but of course at that point the prvalue is not of type array so its a different situation.